# Docker file wait for postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Hello I have the following error in my node project:

> (node:51) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo
>   ENOTFOUND ${DB_HOST}

I'm thinking the problem is that my postgress is not yet started when my project starts
and so I'm not able to think of a solution on how to start my container after my postgres is ready, I read something about dockerize, but I'm not able to imagine how to apply

my **docker file:**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/api

WORKDIR /home/node/api

COPY ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

USER node

RUN yarn

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

my **docker compose:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  ci-api:
    build: .
    container_name: ci-api
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/api
      - /home/node/api/node_modules
    ports:
      - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'
    depends_on:
      - ci-postgres
    networks:
      - ci-network
  ci-postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: ci-postgres
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:5432'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ci-postgres-data:/data
    networks:
      - ci-network

volumes:
  ci-postgres-data:

networks:
  ci-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and this is my **.env**

```
SERVER_PORT=4000
DB_HOST=ci-postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=spirit
DB_PASS=api
DB_NAME=emasa_ci
```

Comment: See this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y/41854997#41854997

Comment: I was very confused, I'm new to docker can u help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can reference the below `docker-compose.yml` in which `depends_on`, `healthcheck` and `links` are added as web service depends on db service.

Reference:
[Postgresql Container is not running in docker-compose file - Why is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110548/postgresql-container-is-not-running-in-docker-compose-file-why-is-this)

```
version: "3"
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    container_name: webapp
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=tmp
      - POSTGRES_USER=tmp
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=tmp_password
    volumes:  # Persist the db data
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  database-data:
```